# Radio buttons pre-populated with previous repsonse

Tags: reactjs, input, radio-button, label, state

I have a function that builds a matrix-grid style question, where you have multiple questions to the left with radio button responses for each question to the right.

My issue is that, when this function is called more than once (you have more than 1 matrix-grid question), the grid is already pre-populated with the responses from the previous matrix-grid question.

It's worth noting that, in my `state` the responses from Question1 are unchanged and despite being pre-populated, the state variables for the second question are actually blank until you start clicking

```
renderFieldlikert(params) {
    var count = 0;
    let matrixQuestion = params.SubFields.map(function(question, x) {
      let questionText = (<li className='left-column'><h4 className='text-left'>{question.Label}</h4></li>);
      let radioButtons = params.Choices.map(function(choice, i) {
        let val = choice.Score
        return(
          <li className='animated fadeIn'>
            <input onChange={(e) => this.props.handleRadioChange(o.ID, e)} type="radio" name={question.Label} id={++count} key={i} value={val} />
            <label htmlFor={count}>{choice.Score}</label>
          </li>
        )
      }.bind(this));

      return(
        <ul>
          {questionText}
          {radioButtons}
        </ul>
      )}.bind(this));
```

Image 1: User answer's questions

Image 2: Answers from question 1 show up in question 2

[image: User answer's questions in first matrix-grid question]

[image: Answers from first question show up here though]

Comment: Please post an example `params` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your returned `<ul>` a unique `key` so that React can identify that you're trying to render different, unique components. React internally optimizes how it handles the DOM and will re-use HTML elements if it thinks that they are supposed to be the same elements.

An easy way to do this is with `Date.now()` which will always be unique every time your function returns a new component.

```
  return(
    <ul key={Date.now()} >
      {questionText}
      {radioButtons}
    </ul>
  )}.bind(this));
```

However the above won't work if you're calling `renderFieldlikert()` on every render, causing React to generate a *new* component every time it renders instead of reusing the same one. `key` should be unique and generated once before using it in a render method. It would be even better if every `param` you pass in has some kind of unique identifier and you used that instead.

```
  // Maybe?
  return(
    <ul key={params.uniqueKey} >
      {questionText}
      {radioButtons}
    </ul>
  )}.bind(this));
```

Comment: I tried this and it went bonkers, I think it was rerendering the entire `<ul>` as I clicked on choices.

Comment: @vin_Bin87 `Date.now()` probably won't work if you're calling `renderFieldlikert()` on every render which I suspect is the case. Ideally `key` will be something unique and generated once, not every render. I edited my response a little, try giving each `param` a unique key before using it for render, or find some way to generate a unique key string using the data already in `param`, perhaps the question label text.

Comment: Yep, giving it a unique `key` pulled from `question` was what did it. The previous didn't work because, like you said it was re-rendering it over and over and each time it was a new `key` so it made it go nutty. Thanks!